# mod_write htaccess with subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to figure out this htaccess issue and I can't seem to get it working and getting stuck on 500 errors.

I've looked around at multiple S.O. questions and general google but haven't found any that apply to my particular situation. Here it is:

I have `example.com`. I want if the user puts in: `example.com` or `www.example.com` to go to `index.php`.

But if the user puts in a subdomain `subdomain.example.com`; I want it to go to

```
dashboard.php?val=subdomain
```

Further more I'd like

```
subdomain.example.com/contact
```

to go to

```
dashboard.php?val=subdomain&page=contact
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If doesn't start with www and it has a subdomain, redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [E=VAL:%1]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dashboard.php?val=%{ENV:VAL}&page=idx
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /dashboard.php?val=%{ENV:VAL}&page=contact  [L]
#Note:  I have tried this with and without the Env variables and only having 1 RewriteRule

# The "catch all other" redirect for images, files and if they do /cont by accident 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dashboard\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . /dashboard.php?val=%1&page=idx - [L]
```

There may be subdomainA and subdomainB, etc so want to do a catch all on subdomains. Hopefully the question makes sense. My Apache knowledge is more limited and most of this is from googling around.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following rules a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.example\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dashboard.php?val=%1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.example\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /dashboard.php?val=%1&page=$0 [NC,L]
```